# Strict mapping in web Web API (Over-Posting)

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api2

I just realized that the mapping between the JSON send from a query and my API is not strict.

I give you more explanations:

Here is my C# POCO

```
public partial class AddressDto
{
    public string AddrId { get; set; }
    public string Addr1 { get; set; }
    public string Addr2 { get; set; }
    public string PostalCode { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
}
```

And the REST JSON query

```
PUT http://Localhost:55328/api/ClientAddr/ADD-2059-S002 HTTP/1.1
content-type: application/json

{
    "AddrID": "ADD-2059-S002",
    "addr1": "B-1/327",
    "addr2": "1ST FLOOR",
    "city": "Paris",
    "Zip_Code": "78956",
    "country": "France",
}
```

The web client send a PUT with Zip_Code in place of PostalCode. PostalCode is not madatory/required. But Zip_Code does not exist in my DTO.

So in my C# code testing the model state won't help.

```
public HttpResponseMessage Put(string id, AddressDto address)
{
     if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            return BadRequest(ModelState); // This wont help
}
```

How can I raise exception when the client is using something in the JSON that is not existing in my DTO (model) ?

Comment: Add validation attributes to the dto

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Documentation : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/model-validation-in-aspnet-web-api

Comment: Read the question please. You link help me to put a word on this: "Over-Posting": A client can also send more data than you expected. but do not propose any solution. Or there is something I don't understand and your comments don't help me.

Comment: Then use a custom model binder that throws exception when it finds a mismatched property in the incoming data to model.

Comment: Ok, so no easy solution or validation attributes.

Comment: Here is another link for model binders https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you need to identify extra columns and handle that as an error you have to extend IModelBinder interface and tell json deserializer to treat extra column as an error and add that error to ModelState. By that way you can check in controller for ModelState.IsValid. Checkout the below Code

CustomModelBinder

```
public class CustomModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public bool BindModel(HttpActionContext actionContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
        settings.MissingMemberHandling = MissingMemberHandling.Error;
        ObjToPass obj = new ObjToPass();
        ;
        try
        {
            ObjToPass s =
                JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ObjToPass>(actionContext.Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result,
                    settings);


            bindingContext.Model = obj;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            bindingContext.ModelState.AddModelError("extraColumn", ex.Message);
        }
        return true;
    }
}

public class CustomerOrderModelBinderProvider : ModelBinderProvider
{
    public override IModelBinder GetBinder(System.Web.Http.HttpConfiguration configuration, Type modelType)
    {
        return new CustomModelBinder();
    }
}
```

Object Class that is passed to webapi

```
 public class ObjToPass
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

}
```

Controller

```
 [HttpPost]
    public void PostValues([ModelBinder(typeof(CustomerOrderModelBinderProvider))] ObjToPass obj)
    {
        if(!ModelState.IsValid)
        { }
        else
        {

        }
    }
```

This sample holds good for HttpPut as well.

Comment: I have added the attribute validation on Model. but after i wrote the custom model binder, the attribute validations are not working. How can we enable the attribute validation in CustomModelbinder?

Answer (score 0):

"Over-Posting": A client can also send more data than you expected. For example:

Here, the JSON includes a property ("Zip_Code") that does not exist in the Address model. In this case, the JSON formatter simply ignores this value. (The XML formatter does the same.)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/model-validation-in-aspnet-web-api