# how can I validate a web api request object for this scenario?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I have an api/v1/users/search uri within a Web API 2.2 project.  This uri accepts a UserSearchRequest object.  Here's a sample:

```
{
"DomainName":"ad.corp.domain",
"NetworkUserId":"jsmith2",
"FirstName":"John",
"LastName":"Smith"
}
```

The backend search logic will append all of the provided request parameter values to filter the set of users returned.  Otherwise, an empty request object will result in all users being returned. However, if a client passes a request like the following then all users will be returned:

```
{
"UserName":"jsmith2"
}
```

In the example above, an invalid proprty of UserName was mistakenly used instead of NetworkUserId.  However, instead of Web API returning an error, it simply ignored the additional property and returned all Users since no valid search criteria property values were provided.

What would be a proper way to validate the incoming request so that if an invalid prpoerty name is provided then Web API will return a 404 BadRequest, and preferably indicate the invalid property name?

Comment: You might consider requiring the field and using something like `*` to mean "all". I can't see any code but I can infer the problem is not that an invalid property was sent so much as deserialization created an object with `null` for that property. And I think you mean `400`, not `404`.

Comment: nope there are 10 search properties and none of them should be required

Comment: You can't have it both ways.

Answer (score 2):

You are facing **The "Over-Posting" Problem**. This can be handled in a couple of different ways :

1. Use the `Bind` attribute and whitelist or blacklist the properties you want.

   ```
    public ActionResult search([Bind(Exclude="UserName")] Person person)
     {
         ...
     }

     public ActionResult search([Bind(Include="DomainName, NetworkUserId, 
       FirstName, LastName")] Person person)
     {
        ...
     }
   ```
2. The other solution is to create a `Custom Model Binder` by extending `IModelBinder`. This will identify the extra columns and handle that as an error. You can check the implementation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42709122/strict-mapping-in-web-web-api-over-posting).

Answer (score 0):

In case of incorrect property names or datatypes, the web api will fail to deserialize the json to UserSearchRequest object and api controller parameter will be null. You can check for null which will indicate that input request was not properly formatted. Here is sample code:

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> SearchUsers([FromBody] UserSearchRequest 
 searchRequest) {
   if(searchRequest == null)
    {
        return BadRequest();
    }
   //For valid search request, continue search...
}
```

Comment: But according to OP this is a valid request and should return all data.

Comment: nope I already have that validation check.  if an additional invalid property is included then web api will simply ignore that property by default

Comment: @Harsh no the request should be considered invalid and  a message should be returned in BadRequest like "UserName is not a valid UserSearchRequest property name"

Comment: One option may be is to set the input parameter datatype as dynamic to receive the input object and then inspect that input search object for additional invalid properties

Answer (score 0):

I think here you are getting the data from Particular x or y table. What you are showing here is returning directory data. It is actually easy part . Controller code you can manage validation. I think you are tying to get "NetworkUserId" but controller you might be changed to username . Please check your datatype . Please attach your controller code and model class.Thank you .